# Best place for other php.class in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

i have a php.class that handle gd-functions in my symfony2-project. Where i can find the best place for this classes?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it to any of your bundles. You sure must have bundles created. Add a directory to your bundle. The directory can be named anything. I normally name it `Services`. Add namespace to your class. Lets say if your bundle name is `AcmeDemoBundle` and your directory name is `Services`, your namespace would be `Acme\Bundles\DemoBundles\Services`

You can then register this class as a service and access via DI.

Comment: That was, what i think, too. I think that is the best way, because i can use it at other controller...

Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder in src/. To autoload the classes that are in the folder you will create, use Composer Autoload feature (https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) or autoload it in /app/ (https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.7/app/autoload.php)

Answer (score 1):

If your Class is also useable without an Symfony2 context you should not place it in `Acme\Bundles\DemoBundle` but rater under `Acme\Components\ChangeThisToWhateverYourLibsNameIs`. Then you can define an service in your bundle for this class to use this as an service in an Symfony context.

**Why?**

Because with this way you can reuse the library in that namespace in other frameworks two. You could maybe create a new composer package for it and add it as an dependency of your bundle.
As you see the Symfony core team does it the same way:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security.xml